# Error: horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "nginx-1-hpa" already exists

Tags: nginx, deployment, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to gcp and kubernetes and while deploying a workload in a cluster I was stuck with this error "Error: horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling "nginx-1-hpa" already exists". Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message that you've shared, it seems that you are trying to create a [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) that already exists.

[To fix this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/), you will have to delete the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler named “nginx-1-hpa”.

The command to delete the HPA "nginx-1-hpa" is:

```
$ kubectl delete hpa  nginx-1-hpa
```

After deleting the HPA, you will be able to deploy the workload.